# Combining sets with a rule

Tags: combinatorics

If we have set $\{a_1\dots,a_n\}$ where $a_i$ are integers, all possible permutations are $n!$.

Now if we have two sets $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$  and $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ with  we want to unite them in one set such that $A\cup B=C=\{c_1,\dots,c_{2n}\}$ . In how many ways can the $a_i$ and the $b_i$ be assigned to the $c_i$, respecting their respective orders?

The answer is  $\binom{2n}n$. Can someone explain why this is the result?

Comment: In how many ways we can create 2n set from two n sets

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: there is only 1 set that is ordered ,I have changed the problem to : if we have 2 sets of n elements and we want to unite them in one with 2n elements in how many ways this can happen

Comment: @ParclyTaxel can you elaborate how do we get to this Binom?

Comment: Think of it this way.  There are 2n empty spaces.  You can choose n of them to be reserved for member of set A.  The rest have to be for set B.  There are ${2n \choose n}$ ways to choose the $n$ spaces for set A.  Once the spaces are chosen, we don't have any choice what order to place the members of the sets in as the order of the original set must be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it in this way. First let's fix that we will first assign $a_{i}$'s and then $b_{i}$'s. Changing this order would not affect our assignments. Now we have $2n$ places for assignment. So we can pick out any $n$ places in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways and put the $a_{i}$'s in the given order. Now we have $n$ places left and have to put the $b_{i}$'s in the given order. There is only one way left for this. So our total possible ways are $\binom{2n}{n}*1=\binom{2n}{n}$.